# Can we select data from 2 tables in same time

Tags: sql

From the code as shown below. I wonder that why it can select data from 2 tables in same time that are table "venue AS v" and table "as s".

or I misunderstand?

```
SELECT name, s.num_match
FROM venue AS v, 
(SELECT venue_id, COUNT(*) AS num_match
    FROM match
    GROUP BY venue_id) AS s
WHERE v.venue_id = s.venue_id
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: What is your question? Read any kind of sql documentation and you may gain some knowledge.

Comment: s is known as a derived table. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using JOIN clause for example.
More infos here: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=5

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can select data from as many as tables you want at the same time.
In this case you are trying to get an aggregated number from table-s and join it with the table v.
There are many ways to write the code to join the table. Above is one method which you have used.